# Countdown to function

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown js script which counts down for 30 seconds, pauses for 10 seconds. I would like to make it so during that 10 seconds, a function runs. I'm unaware how to do this, any suggestions of methods?

**Code if you'd like to see it...**

Here's my countdown script

```
var serverTimeOffset = <?php echo microtime(true); ?> - new Date().getTime()/1000;

function getServerTime() {
    return new Date().getTime()/1000 + serverTimeOffset;
}

function updateCountdown() {
    var time = Math.max(30 - (getServerTime() % 40), 0);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time.toFixed(2);        
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCountdown);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    updateCountdown();
});
```

Here's the desired script I'd like to run at the end of each countdown

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'api.php',                          
        data: "",                                
        dataType: 'json',                      
        success: function(data){
            var id = data[0]; 
            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: that is one weird way of doing a countdown without an interval...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It does have an interval of 10 seconds

Comment: and where is the particular code with `setInterval` then?! fix the code in your question!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).